# AssertEqual Doesnt Throw an Error even if Values are Different

Tags: python, numbers, hex, decimal, assertion

I have this code in Python

```
import unittest



class AES_TEST(unittest.TestCase):


    def test_encryption(self):
        print('Encryption : ')
        plaintext = 0x3243f6a8885a308d313198a2e0370734
        encrypted = 75960790320075369159181001580855561010
        print(encrypted)
        print('0x3925841d02dc09fbdc118597196a0b32')

        self.assertEqual(encrypted, 0x3925841d02dc09fbdc118597196a0b32)

    def test_decryption(self):
        print('Decryption : ')
        ciphertext = 0x3925841d02dc09fbdc118597196a0b32
        decrypted = self.AES.decrypt(ciphertext)
        decrypted = 66814286504060421741230023322616923956
        print(decrypted)
        print('0x3243f6a8885a308d313198a2e0370734')


        self.assertEqual(decrypted, 0x3243f6a8885a308d313198a2e0370734)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Why does it doesn't throw an error? Why does `encrypted`  variable is equal to `0x3925841d02dc09fbdc118597196a0b32` , when in fact they have different values? The same behavior is also observe in `decryption` variable.

Comment: The numbers are equal but only represented differently as hexadecimal value (prefixed with `0x`) and decimal value (no prefix). `0xa == 10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are equal.

the 0x in front of a number means that the representation is base 16 (hex).  If you use a [calculator](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html) to convert `0x3925841d02dc09fbdc118597196a0b32` to decimal format, you will see it is the same value assigned to it in that block of code.